# Custom view's content in stack view are not visible even when on view debugger it is showing a proper frame?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

This is the code for my custom view;

```
import UIKit

class TodoCell: UIView {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var radioButton: UIImageView!
var isTaskDone: Bool = false

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    customInit()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    customInit()
}

func configure(title: String) {
    self.label.text = title
}

func customInit() {
    if let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TodoCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? TodoCell {
        view.frame = bounds
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        addSubview(view)
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    radioButton.image = UIImage(named: "radio_button_unchecked")
 }
}
```

This is how I am adding my custom view inside stack view

```
        let view = TodoCell(frame: .zero)
        view.configure(title: $0.title)
        todoListStackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
        todoListStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90).isActive = true
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: todoListStackView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

The highlighted cell is a TodoCell inside stackview.

[image]

This is my TodoCell xib.

[image]

Comment: It's a little confusing what you're trying to do... You have a `UITableViewCell` **xib** ... and you want to load the **view** from that xib and add it as an arranged subview of a stack view? Are you using a table view at all?

Comment: The xib is not of tableviewcell. it's of todocell

Answer (score 0):

OK - based on the xib image you posted, it looks like you have the custom class for `File's Owner` set to `TodoCell`.

However, in this part of your code:

```
func customInit() {
    if let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TodoCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? TodoCell {
        view.frame = bounds
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

your `if` statement says "Only do this if the view (the `[0]` object) from the xib is a `TodoCell`. With the way you've configured your xib, that is not the case.

Also, you want to set the `autoresizingMask` on the loaded view.

So, assuming you have constraints setup correctly in your xib, if you change that to:

```
func customInit() {
    if let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("OldTodoCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? UIView {
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

you should be on your way.

A side note...

Using "cell" when naming a custom view can be confusing, as anyone else would assume it's a table view or collection view cell. If you're the only person who will ever touch your code, that doesn't matter. But, it's something to consider.